# How to pass string arrays into an attribute constructor?

Tags: c#

**Edit:**
Thanks to @Sweeper for pointing out that the particular issue encountered in my example below has already been addressed in [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437821/6817821) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402943/why-is-the-compiler-giving-an-error-because-of-a-non-constant-expression-when-pa). This does not directly answer the question, but does provide the workarounds necessary due to what appears to be a compiler bug.

**Original Question:**
I am having trouble reconciling some behavior I have observed with attribute argument types with what is stated in the official documentation. In [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235690/6817821) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235617/how-to-pass-objects-into-an-attribute-constructor), he quotes from ECMA 334v4 where it says:

> §24.1.3 Attribute parameter types
>
> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `short`, `string`.
> - The type `object`.
> - The type `System.Type`.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility.
> - ***Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.***

[This MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes#how-to-add-attributes-to-code) on attributes also states that

> Parameters to an attribute constructor are limited to simple types/literals: `bool`, `int`, `double`, `string`, `Type`, enums, etc ***and arrays of those types***.

(emphasis mine in both quotes)

However, when I attempt to declare an attribute parameter of type `string[]`, I get this error:

> An attribute argument array creation must be single-dimension array of 'object[]' type

```
// OK
[TestCase(new[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13})]
public void TestIntArrayArgs(int[] intArr)
{
    // Run test . . .
}

// Compiler error:
// "An attribute argument array creation must be single-dimension array of 'object[]' type"
[TestCase(new[] {"A", "B"})]
public void TestStringArrayArgs(string[] strArr)
{
    // Run test . . .
}
```

I should note that if I wanted only one array of strings, using a `params[]` argument for the test method would suffice; however, I want two arrays.

Can anyone spot what I am missing?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402943/why-is-the-compiler-giving-an-error-because-of-a-non-constant-expression-when-pa)

Answer (score 3):

As [@JasparKent points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403175/6817821) in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402943/why-is-the-compiler-giving-an-error-because-of-a-non-constant-expression-when-pa), providing a `string[]` argument does work if you used named arguments, like this:

```
[TestCase(arg: new[] {"A", "B"})]
public void TestStringArrayArgs(string[] strArr)
{
    // Run test . . .
}
```

This is due to an overload conflict between two of the `TestCaseAttribute` constructors (which I examined via JetBrains Decompiler):

```
public TestCaseAttribute(params object[] arguments) { . . . }
public TestCaseAttribute(object arg) { . . . }
```

This solves my original problem. To those looking for an answer to the question as I originally asked it, [John Skeet's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437821/6817821) to the same question does  examine in more detail the underlying issue of converting a `string[]` parameter to an `object[]` parameter.